# How Calculate Average Of Minutes and Seconds In Excel

Tags: excel

My raw data in column B each on a new line looks like this:-
5.04,3.57,0.58,10.01
Left of . is minutes and right of . is seconds.
I need to calculate the average of my data . How do I go about this?

Comment: Convert them to a true time in a new column.

Comment: @BigBen How do I convert to "true time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to convert to a true time; one option is to use `TIME` and parse the raw data:</strike>

In a new column, use:

```
=TIME(,LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)),MID(B1,FIND(".",B1)+1,999))
```

[image]

Another option is to use `TIMEVALUE`:

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",":"))
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Use `TEXT` to force the raw times to retain a trailing zero when parsing:

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(B5,"00.00"),".",":"))
```

[image]

Another option, probably the best one actually, is just a bit of math:

```
=TIME(,TRUNC(B1),(B1-TRUNC(B1))*100)
```

[image]

Comment: I have picked up a problem with both your formulas. 4.10 converts to 00:04:01 and 5.30 converts to 00:05:03 . The problem always occurs where the last digit of my number is a zero. Any solution?

Comment: @Anthony - see the edit, my bad, did not think about that case.